# Как пробросить события через родительский компонент? (Angular)

Tags: typescript, angular, input, события

Имеются несколько компонентов и поле ввода:

```
Компонент 1 -> компонент 2 -> ... -> input
```

Необходимо получать события поля ввода в компоненте 1

Я знаю такой способ решения, создавать в каждом компоненте @Output EventEmitter и привязывать эти их к полю:

```
  /** Передача значения поля */
  @Output() onValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  /** Передача события blur */
  @Output() onBlur: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  /** Передача события focus*/
  @Output() onFocus: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  <input type="text"
    (input)="this.onValueChange.emit($event)" 
    (blur)="this.onBlur.emit($event)"
    (focus)="this.onFocus.emit($event)"/>
```

Есть ли способ не множить эмиттеры для разных событий? Или существует какой-то более лучший способ это сделать?

Comment: Добавился такой вариант: создать единый EventEmitter для передачи всех событий в родительский компонент, затем в компоненте проверять event.type и в зависимости от типа распределять действия